# How do you add a folder not under your project folder in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have two separate visual Studio 12 C# project with the following folder structure.  The Common folder contains classes that are common to both projects.

\CompanyName\Site\Product\ProjectA\SRC - 
\CompanyName\Site\Product\Projectb\SRC
\CompanyName\Site\Product\Common\SRC

how can I include the Common\SRC folder and subfolders in each project without having to copy the folder into the project SRC folders?2

Comment: add the common project to your solution and add the reference of common to your project.

Comment: if you have a class that is common to both projects then put the class in the app_data or some helpers folder and give it a namespace that both can utilize / gain access to it.. you don't need 2 copies of the same class

Comment: I am using the folder as the namespace so they are different.  I don't want two copies of the same code.  The common folder is not a project just common classes that I want to use in both projects.

Comment: Visual Studio will not allow me to add and existing folder only files.  The files are not in a folder but in the top level of the project.

Comment: Why do you not make Common a class library and then reference it from your other two projects?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by adding existing folders/files as links. By using links you can have files in one location but link them into multiple projects.

A simple way to link files is to drag and drop them into a folder in your project while holding the ALT key (you will see an arrow next to files).

This method also works with folders and subfolders. In this case drag and drop (while holding ALT) the top folder that you want to include.

For more info on how to link existing files see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306234

Comment: Is there a way to add the folder structure with the link?  If I have five folders with 20 files each I will have 100 link files in the solution folder window under the project.  Rather than 5 folders with 20 files in the folders?

Comment: Yes. Adding the top folder will add the whole folder structure. Inside your project you can then simply close the folder (by clicking on the arrow left of it) to hide subfolders and files so they are not in your way.

Comment: Is there a way to add a class to the linked folder, If I add a new class, visual studio creates the folder structure within the project and adds the file to that folder stucture.

Comment: Not that I know of. You have to open the original location (you can right-click on one of the linked folders/files and click Open In File Explorer then you have to create or copy the file there and link it into the project. Newer versions of VS (2013) add Shared projects for some project types that cover that functionality as well.